# Помогите создать запрос в postgreSQL на выборку данных

Tags: sql, postgresql

Задача :
Составить запрос на выборку данных:
Есть таблица:
[image: Таблица]

```
CREATE TABLE cars
(
    id                  serial NOT NULL,
    vin                 varchar(20) UNIQUE,
    brand               varchar(50),
    model               varchar(50),
    year_of_manufacture smallint,
    price               int,
    mileage             int,
    selling_price       int,
    sold                boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Мне необходимо выбрать машины только , которые проданы (sold = true)

Пытаюсь сделать запрос :

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE sold = TRUE
```

Ловлю ошибку :

```
ERROR: ОШИБКА:  оператор не существует: smallint = boolean
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM cars WHERE sold = TRUE
                                      ^
HINT:  Оператор с данными именем и типами аргументов не найден. Возможно, вам следует добавить явные приведения типов.
```

Все это происходит в pgAdmin
[image: pgAdmin]
Помогите:)
Ранее использовал MySQL , использовал tinyint(1) и держал в таблце 0 и 1 , мигрировал на postgres, решил сделать в таблице boolean )

Но как сделать такой запрос, не понимаю)

Update:

Теперь совсем ничего не понимаю

[image: Как так]

Вопрос решен, было 2 схемы... и одна была такая : столбец sold был smallint.

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке не принадлежит PostgreSQL. Предъявляйте претензии своей программе-клиенту. PS. На показанных структуре и тексте запроса показанная проблема - не соответствует фактическому положению дел.

Comment: Ток я ведь делаю это в pgAdmin, Я чтоб именно убедится что проблема в postgres , делаю все в pgAdmin 4

Comment: Ну смотри сам. Сообщение говорит "оператор не существует: smallint = boolean". Сравнение в запросе выглядит как *sold = TRUE*. TRUE - это предопределённая константа, и smallint быть не может. Значит, как smallint интерпретируется `sold`. Но в структуре он явно определён как boolean. Противоречие неразрешимо. Ну-ка, нахрен этот pgAdmin, смотри всё то же штатными средствами.

Comment: Спасибо!
Проблема оказалась в том , что изначально я таблицу отправил ещё пока столбец был не boolean, а smailint в схему "public".

А потом создал новую схему и пытался с ней работать.
а pgAdmin и IntelliJ Idea работали все это время с public.
А там естественно была старая таблица.